# Adding query in FutureBuilder to retrieve data just for logged user and his information Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have this list into a Futurebuilder Widget that retrieve documents from Firestore database-.
I have created query to retrieve data from a specific collection in Firestore.
I need to add into the query a instance to retrieve data just for logged user and his information not the information of the other.
this is my code:

```
class CollectData extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CollectDataState createState() => _CollectDataState();
}

class _CollectDataState extends State<CollectData> {
  final String phone;
  final String wife;
  final String location;


  _CollectDataState({
    this.phone,
    this.wife,
    this.location,

  });


  Future<QuerySnapshot> getData() async {
    var User = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    return await Firestore.instance
        .collection("dataCollection")
        .getDocuments();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: getData(),
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          return ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Column(
                  children: [
                    Text('${snapshot.data.documents[index].data["wife"]}'),
                    Text('${snapshot.data.documents[index].data["phone"]}'),
                    Text('${snapshot.data.documents[index].data["location"]}'),
                  ],
                );
              });
        } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.none) {
          return Text("No data");
        }
        return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      },
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Solution found:

```
Future<QuerySnapshot> getData() async {
    var User = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    return await Firestore.instance
        .collection("dataCollection")
        .where(FieldPath.documentId, isEqualTo: User.uid )
        .getDocuments();
  }
```

Comment: This .where(FieldPath.documentId, isEqualTo: User.uid ) overwrite the previous document any suggestion to create a new one and not overwrite ^?

Comment: But you are retrieving an existing document... it should be caught in a different statement? https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data